# Constant problems with pidgin

Tags: authentication, gmail, pidgin

I am having the hardest time finding a solution to this pidgin problem. I have been using it for a long time, but recently it has quit connecting for me. Every time I try to connect, it tells me my account is disabled and not authorized.

Here is what I have it set up like:

- protocol: xmpp
- username:  name of email
- domain: gmail.com
- password: my password for that email account

Now, I have recently set up 2-factor authentication for this email account, and I am wondering if that has anything to do with it. However, I haven't been able to find any research in regard to that change, so I'm baffled.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google search "pidgin google 2fa" -> https://productforums.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/apps/Eg2LD8U28qs#!topic/apps/Eg2LD8U28qs

Comment: I tried to update the title to better reflect the underlying problem: "Constant problems with Pidgin with XMPP (gmail.com): account disabled or not authorized" but the edit queue is full now. Current title is "Constant problems with pidgin".

Answer (score 2):

"Allow less secure apps: ON" using below link. Gmail consider pidgin as less security Application.

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Answer (score 0):

You have activated 2FA (two factor authentication) that consists in requiring a code in addition to the password.

Since Pidgin (and many other apps) don't consider this step in the login flow, you need to somehow use a password again, skipping 2FA. How to do this?

The solution is using an "App Password" when logging via Pidgin: these are generated passwords of 16 characters that you can use in places where the 2FA flow isn't considered.

More info about using App Passwords on Google accounts: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I was also constantly getting this “not-authorized” and "Mobile_number disabled” message. My environments were Ubuntu 14.04/15.04, I am using my mobile no as the user name and generated a WhatsApp password by registering my mobile with Yowsup.

After installing fresh (by compiling from source) and registering the mobile number again with Yowsup, it was still giving the same error. Just did the following and it resolved the above issue for my case.

Accounts > Modify Account > Advanced > Delete whatever default value is being shown in the “Resource” field which in my case was “Android-2.12.5-443”. 
Then go into Account > Manage Account again > and check mark the “Enabled” box for your Account.

Then for sometime I had to do this step every time I restart Pidgin. Only couple of days back from [this github issue page](https://github.com/davidgfnet/whatsapp-purple/issues/275) came to know that Current whatsapp android version is 2.12.176. So, changed the "Resource" field value to "Android-2.12.176" - And now everything is working perfectly.